# Testing super class fields

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

```
//super Class
public class B
{
  protected sum s1 = new sum();
  protected sub  s2 = new sub();
  public B()
  {
    this.con = con;
    this.d = d;
  }

  public method_demo()
  {
// code here
   }
}



public class A extends B
{
   public method_1(Connection con , Dummy d)
   {
       super(con,d) ;
   }
}
```

In order to test class A, the super class constructor is called first.
How to write test case for it. I tried suppressing the fields in the super class but still it is giving initialization error.

Comment: What is giving an initialization error?

Comment: You are confusing methods with constructors. Your code is illegal.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense. You have a method that tries to be a constructor, and a constructor that's trying to assign variables that don't exist.

Comment: In my opinion this should even not compile. I think you have errors in declaration of constructor of class B

Comment: Please read the book your teachers gave you.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I think you want:

```
public class B
{
    protected sum s1 = new sum();
    protected sub s2 = new sub();

    Connection con;
    Dummy d;

    public B(Connection con, Dummy d)
    {
        this.con = con;
        this.d = d;
    }

    public method_demo()
    {

    }
}

public class A extends B
{
    //this is a constructor, because is has the same name as the class
    public A(Connection con, Dummy d)
    {
        super(con, d);
    }
    /* // This is a method, not a constructor:
    public method_1(Connection con , Dummy d)
    {
        super(con,d) ;
    }
    */
}
```